# C++ class Remove ambiguity

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance, ambiguity

How to call the function sum from instance of class E without modifying the class definitions.
I have define 2 classes with same function. And inherited both of them in two different classes. Now how can i access the sum from object E.

```
class A {
public:
    int sum(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }
};


class F {
public:
    int sum(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }
};

class B: public A, public F {

};

class C: public A, public F {

};

class E: public B, public C {

};

int32_t main() {
  
    E d;
    cout << d.A::B::sum(3, 4);

}
```

Comment: To get to A thru B, that would be B::A, not A::B (A doesn't have a B).

Comment: You can simply use `cout << d.A::sum(3, 4);` for A's version, and `cout << d.F::sum(3, 4);` for F's version. These are anyway the only 2 implementations of the function.

Comment: @wohlstad Not really, `E` has two `A` and two `F` bases. You have to disambiguate that too.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I agree. But I didn't see any point refering to the available implementations (in A and F) other than by `A::sum` or `F::sum`. Is there anything I am missing ? At least Visual Studio binded these 2 methods correcetly when I tried.

Comment: @wohlstad It shouldn't compile, no idea why MSVC decides it's ok (and how does it choose which `A` object to call it on) https://godbolt.org/z/hvGaEGh7E

Comment: @Yksisarvinen MSVC appears to just arbitrarily follow the leftmost branch. [Here's an example](https://godbolt.org/z/Me8W3q5Wa) where two branches produce different results. MSVC prints `889` (you'll have to take my word for it as godbolt can't run MSVC code). And yes, this looks like MSVC bug; the code is ill-formed and shouldn't compile.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen - I see. Now I am uncertain as well. Thanks for the Compiler Explorer link.

Answer (score 2):

```
static_cast<B&>(d).A::sum(3, 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

While @IgorTandetnik's answer is valid, it is not what I would recommend.

The `sum()` methods you described should simply *not* be methods. They don't require privileged access to other members of classes A and B respectively, so - they should simply be freestanding functions (or at most: static methods). This is principle [C.4 of the C++ coding guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rc-member).

If you minimize a class' set of methods to those which are actually necessary, you will have a lot fewer cases of such ambiguity; and your classes will likely be easier to understand and maintain.

In your case, you even have two methods with related functionality, so it's possible you  might be able to have a single `sum()` function (perhaps templated?) for both classes.